# makefile implicit rule -- confused

Tags: gcc, makefile

I am working on a project where makefile is used to make an target.
Here i am confused how makefile is generating .o files from the .cpp file.

Like file clientthread_level1_unix.o have to be generated from clientthread_level1_unix.cpp file.
But no where it is specified to use *.cpp file for it.

```
EXTRALIBS = -pthread -lz -ldl -lm
OPENGLLIBS =
LDFLAGS_GL =
LDLIBS = ${APPEXTRALIBS} ${top_builddir}/lib/libwx_based-2.6.a ${EXTRALIBS}

# Compiler used
CXX         = c++
CC          = gcc

CANALOBJS =     ../../common/listenthread_unix.o ../../common/clientthread_level1_unix.o ../../common/devicethread_unix.o \
        ../../common/canalshmem_level1_unix.o ../../common/clientlist.o ../../common/controlobject.o \
        ../../common/devicelist.o ../../common/udpreceivethread_unix.o ../../../vscp/common/vscp.o \
        ../../common/clientthread_level2_unix.o ../../common/canalshmem_level2_unix.o \
        ../../common/tcplistenthread.o
CANALHDRS = ../../common/clientlist.h ../../common/controlobject.h ../../common/devicelist.h \
        ../../common/canal.h ../../common/canaldlldef.h \
        ../../common/version.h ../../common/canal_unix_ipc.h ../../common/CanalShMem_level1_unix.h \
        ../../common/CanalShMem_level2_unix.h ../../common/clientthread_level1_unix.h ../../common/clientthread_level2_unix.h
PROJOBJS    = ../../../common/dllist.o ../../../common/configfile.o ../../../common/crc.o
PROJHDRS    = ../../../common/dllist.h ../../../common/configfile.h
OBJS        = canald.o
HDRS        = canald.h


all:        canald

# Build the Linux executable
canald:     $(OBJS) $(HDRS) $(CANALOBJS) $(CANALHDR) $(PROJOBJS) $(PROJHDRS)
        $(CXX) $(OBJS) $(CANALOBJS) $(PROJOBJS) -o canald $(LIBS) $(LDLIBS)
```

If we use the Implicit rule then also, then also **canald** target is not as per that.
http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#make-Deduces
http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules

Please sugest how is this line working to produce **canald** ?

```
    $(CXX) $(OBJS) $(CANALOBJS) $(PROJOBJS) -o canald $(LIBS) $(LDLIBS)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
 $(CXX) $(OBJS) $(CANALOBJS) $(PROJOBJS) -o canald $(LIBS) $(LDLIBS)
```

will approximately (I skipped not defined variables) be translated into:

```
 c++  canald.o ../../common/listenthread_unix.o ../../common/clientthread_level1_unix.o ../../common/devicethread_unix.o \
    ../../common/canalshmem_level1_unix.o ../../common/clientlist.o ../../common/controlobject.o \
    ../../common/devicelist.o ../../common/udpreceivethread_unix.o ../../../vscp/common/vscp.o \
    ../../common/clientthread_level2_unix.o ../../common/canalshmem_level2_unix.o \
    ../../common/tcplistenthread.o \
    ../../../common/dllist.o ../../../common/configfile.o ../../../common/crc.o \
    -o canald /lib/libwx_based-2.6.a -pthread -lz -ldl -lm
```

i.e., a "normal" compiler call. Since there is an explicit rule for `canald`, there is no need to search for implicite ones. In addition, it is the target rule in the `Makefile`, thus it is the default target.

Howerver, for objects `canald` depends on, no explicit rule exist, thus the implicit rules are used.

If you want to know, which implicit rules exist, call `make -p` and search in the output for the pattern, e.g. in your case for `%.cpp`.

Comment: so you mean to say that make will automatically apply implicit rule like %.cpp for the existing makefile ---- or i have to apply it manually.

Comment: It is the idea of "implicit" rules that there is no need to apply the explicitly. Even more, except of the main target, `make` deduces always automatically which rules to apply. Thus, you may write rules into your `Makefiles` that will never be applied (because the is no need to do so).

Comment: Thanks, what i got is make will apply this implicit rule on its own and there is no need to specify it explicitly. right ?

Comment: @Katoch: As long a implicit rule fits your requirements, there is no need to _redefine_ it. A rule's _application_ follows always target dependencies.